# Mixing UITextView and plain Title/Right Detail cells in same iOS iPhone app tableview

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitextview, tableview, subview

I've researched many StackOverflow.com questions, and there seems to be a lot of
confusion over how to get a UITextView displayed into a cell of a Table(View).  Here's what
I want:  a table where cell rows 0 and 3, for example, are simple Title/Right Detail text cells, and where cells (rows) 1 & 2 have embedded UITextViews that display a clickable phone number and a clickable URL for a website, respectively.

My first attempt set up and allocated UITextView subViews outside of the "if (cell == nil)"
code block:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize infoTableData;
@synthesize infoDetailTableData;
@synthesize cellImages;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.infoTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Address",     @"Telephone", @"Website", @"Hours", @"Reservations", @"Parking", @"Takeout", @"Cash only?", nil];

    self.cellImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   @"compass_24x24.png",
                   @"mobilephone2_24x24.png",
                   @"web_24x24.png",
                   @"calendar_24x24.png",
                   @"clock2_24x24.png",
                   @"parking_meter_24x24.png",
                   @"shopping_bag_24x24.png",
                   @"credit_cards_24x24.png", nil];

    self.infoDetailTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"123 Main St.",
                            @"555-555-5555",
                            @"www.genericrestaurant.com",
                            @"11:30-2:30,Su:11;5:30-10;F-Sa:10:30,Su:9",
                            @"Recommended",
                            @"Parking lot (in rear); on-street",
                            @"No",
                            @"Credit cards accepted", nil];

}

#pragma mark Table Source, Delegate Protocol code
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.infoTableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ATTEMPT #1:  place subView allocate code outside of 'if (cell == nil)' block...
    // Causes cell corruption issues upon table scrolling...
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"DetailInfoCell"; // same ID as used in storyBoard cell setup...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:14.0f];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.infoTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.cellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];   // ditto: cellImages = array of strings
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

    // Add UITextView to cell for phone, website rows
    if (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";

        // Using constants = embarrassing hack -- figure out proper way
        UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + (cell.frame.size.width)/2.1f,
                                            cell.frame.origin.y + 2.0f,
                                            (cell.frame.size.width)/2.0f,
                                            cell.frame.size.height)];
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
        else
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

        tv.editable = NO;
        tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        //tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;    // or use this instead?
        tv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
        tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tv.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        tv.text=[self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:tv];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
@end
```

But when I scrolled the table, cell contents overwrote each other.  After further research on this website, I learned that it's supposedly a big no-no to set up and allocate the UITextView subViews outside of the "if (cell == nil)" block, because when a cell is dequeued for re-use (using "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"), it may already have had a UITextView subView added to it, so UITextView subViews will be added to cells that already have them, which causes cell corruption issues during scrolling.

So my second attempt tried to get around that problem by using tags to keep track of cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    // ATTEMPT #2:  put subView allocate block INSIDE 'if (cell == nil)' block
    // Now, subViews are blank -- they do not appear in the cell rows (even during scrolling)
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"DetailInfoCell"; // same ID as used in storyBoard cell setup...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    UITextView *tv1 = nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        // Using constants = embarrassing hack -- figure out proper way
        UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + (cell.frame.size.width)/2.1f,
                                                                      cell.frame.origin.y + 2.0f,
                                                                      (cell.frame.size.width)/2.0f,
                                                                      cell.frame.size.height)];

        tv.tag = indexPath.row;     // keep track of this cell, for later re-use...

        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
        else
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

        tv.editable = NO;
        tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        //tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;    // or use this instead?
        tv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
        tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tv.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        tv.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:tv];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:14.0f];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.infoTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];   // infoTableData = data source array of strings...

    if (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        tv1 = (UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: indexPath.row];    // get pointer to 'correct' re-usable cell...
        tv1.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This second attempt failed.  The UITextViews weren't showing up at all.  The cell 
"detail text areas" were blank.

Yet more research on this site revealed postings which claimed that you had to clear any
subViews on returned cells from the call to [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...], 
so that adding a new UITextView subView to the cell wouldn't cause problems.  So my third
attempt tried this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    // ATTEMPT #3:  keep subView allocate code INSIDE 'if (cell == nil)' block; try to clear subViews from cells
    // Still does not work: subViews still blank
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"DetailInfoCell"; // same ID as used in storyBoard cell setup...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    UITextView *tv1 = nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        // Using constants = embarrassing hack -- figure out proper way
        UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + (cell.frame.size.width)/2.1f,
                                                                      cell.frame.origin.y + 2.0f,
                                                                      (cell.frame.size.width)/2.0f,
                                                                      cell.frame.size.height)];

        tv.tag = indexPath.row;     // keep track of this cell, for later re-use...

        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
        else
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

        tv.editable = NO;
        tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        //tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;    // or use this instead?
        tv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
        tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tv.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        tv.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:tv];
    }
    else
    {
        // Clear subviews, if any?

        // Tried this:  did not work: subViews still blank
        [[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];

        // Tried this:  did not work: subViews still blank
        for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews)
        {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
         }
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:14.0f];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.infoTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];   // infoTableData = data source array of strings...

    if (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        tv1 = (UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: indexPath.row];    // get pointer to 'correct' re-usable cell...
        tv1.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This had no affect whatsoever.  UITextView subViews were still not appearing in the cells.

Yet even more research.  Yet another posting said that:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

will *always* return a cell in iOS6, so that code within the "if (cell == nil)" block
will never even execute -- the returned cell will never be nil.  Sure enough, that's
what I found out:  no breakpoint was ever being reached inside my "if (cell == nil)"
code block -- the code was never being executed.

My fourth attempt was just to add a "magic" line of code that yet another posting
suggested:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

which I'm guessing roughly translates to:  "always return a new cell, not a used
one, and don't worry about performance or memory issues" (I sense the internet-sphere rolling its eyes at about this point), and sure enough, that did the trick, once I removed the UITextView allocate/setup code from within the "if (cell == nil)" and put it back where it was originally (outside the block, so that it *always* executes).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{          
    // ATTEMPT #4:
    // According to one particular posting on StackOverflow.com, 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' will
    // *always* return a cell in iOS6 and above. Go figure...  Use 'nil' for cell id on
    // dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
    // For some reason, this works...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:14.0f];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.infoTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.cellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

    if (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";

        UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + (cell.frame.size.width)/2.1f,
                                                                   cell.frame.origin.y + 2.0f,
                                                                   (cell.frame.size.width)/2.0f,
                                                                   cell.frame.size.height)];
        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
        else if (indexPath.row == 2)
            tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

        tv.editable = NO;
        tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        //tv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;    // or use this instead?
        tv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
        tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tv.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        tv.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tv];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12.0f];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.infoDetailTableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But this seems to be a hack.  Can someone post some very simple, basic iPhone
app code (I guess for iOS6/4S or equivalent, but does it really matter?) that
represents the canonical, proper way to fill a TableView so that some rows
are simple Title/Right Detail "text-only" cells, and some cells are UITextView
subView cells with phone numbers/website links in the "details" section?  Am
I required to subClass a UITableViewCell or use some "prepareForReuse"
method?

Note: I'm using a storyBoard to set up one, Dynamic Prototype cell, with an
identifier 'string'.

Comment: You ask about textViews, but never mention editing.  Do you really want non-editable text that looks and acts like a web link?

Comment: Yes, I really want non-editable text (text views) that look and act like web links (& clickable phone numbers).  That's why I'm using tv.dataDetectorTypes.  Is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: That is, I want the "right detail text" part of a Title/Right Detail table style cell to be a phone number that the user can simply touch to initiate a phone call, or touch to open a website.